# Number of Islands LeetCode Q200

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to do Q.200. Number of Islands question on Leetcode. The question reads as the following:

> Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

```
Example 1:

Input:
11110
11010
11000
00000

Output: 1


Example 2:

Input:
11000
11000
00100
00011

Output: 3
```

Below is my solution in JavaScript:

```
/**
 * @param {character[][]} grid
 * @return {number}
 */
var numIslands = function(grid) {
    if (grid.length == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    var count = 0;

    var z = new Array(grid[0].length).fill(0);
    var visit = new Array(grid.length);

    for (i = 0; i < visit.length; i++) {
        visit[i] = z;
    }

    function traverse(x, y, grid, visit, count) {
        var col = grid.length;
        var row = grid[0].length;
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < row && y < col) {
            visit[x][y] = 1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        if (grid[x][y] != 1) {
            return;
        } else {
            traverse(x + 1, y);
            traverse(x - 1, y);
            traverse(x, y + 1);
            traverse(x, y - 1);
            count++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
            if (visit[i][j] == 0) {
                traverse(i, j, grid, visit, count);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
};
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to call a recursion whenever the value is 1, and stop when there is nowhere to traverse (end of the island), then increase the island count by 1. I created an array of 0 to check if the location is visited or not. If it is visited either by for loops or recursion, it becomes a 1, otherwise, it is 0.

It has an error of

```
Line 20 in solution.js
         var col = grid.length;

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Could somebody help me to point out my mistake, please? I spent all morning trying to figure out what is wrong with my solution.

Best regards.

Comment: Your `traverse` accepts 5 arguments, you call it with two.

Answer (score 0):

In Lines 30-33 you have the following which seems to be wrong:

```
        traverse(x + 1, y);
        traverse(x - 1, y);
        traverse(x, y + 1);
        traverse(x, y - 1);
```

Instead of that you can add

```
        traverse(x + 1, y, grid, visit, count);
        traverse(x - 1, y, grid, visit, count);
        traverse(x, y + 1, grid, visit, count);
        traverse(x, y - 1, grid, visit, count);
```

Comment: I did what you said, got an error: RangeError： Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: That is because your approach is incorrect, please read about Graph Traversal Algorithms (DFS and BFS), They will be handy in this question.

Comment: Hi @sd5869, thanks for replying, could you tell me where I did wrong in my codes, please?

Comment: In your code time complexity is exponential O(n^4), so due to this the call of traverse() function increases exponentially and this gives an error RangeError： Maximum call stack size exceeded. So you need to optimize your program. If you run it for 1000*1000 size grid you will get an error.